# Does the definition of $R^3$ requires orthonormal basis?

Tags: vector-spaces

Does the definition of $R^3$ requires orthonormal basis?

If I have a vector space V that consists of 3 linear independent
basis {$v_1,v_2,v_3$} which are not orthonormal, can I
still call it $R^3$?

It seemed people generally use $R^3$ to mean orthonormal basis,
What's the definition of $R^3$(or even, $R^n$)? does
it requires orthonormal basis?

Comment: Your question is unclear. The definition of $\Bbb R^n$ is $$\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mid \forall i\in[1..n]\;x_i\in\Bbb R\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the same in $\mathbb R^2$.

Let us consider $\cos$ and $\sin$. $$\cos'=-\sin\land \cos"=-\cos$$ $$\sin'=\cos 
 \land \sin''=-\sin$$
Both functions are solutions of $$y''+y=0$$and we know that $$S:=\{f:f''+f=0\}=\{\alpha \cos+\beta \sin| (\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2\}$$
So, in a first approach (in mathematics, we say that there is an isomorphism of vector spaces) each solution is written$$(\alpha, \beta)\in \mathbb R^2$$

We could write $$S=\mathbb R^2$$

No need to have an orthonormal basis to consider $\mathbb R^2$ as S

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. In the context of abstract algebra, one may say that anything that's isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ "is" $\mathbb{R}^n$, because the fact that an isomorphism exists implies that all algebraic properties are preserver. However, if you have specific scalar products on your vector spaces, then it might not be smart to say that they are the same unless the isomorphism $\Phi$ between them satisfies something like $(\Phi(a),\Phi(b))=(a,b)$. The question of whether some two objects are "the same" is sometimes a little bit more nuanced and really depends on the general question you're trying to answer.